# Split data in one cell

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that some cells contain a number of information in one cell, as below one:

```
192.168.1.1/24
198.255.4.1/23
192.168.2.5/24
255.255.10.0
1.1.1.1
```

I need to split each row within the same cell to be in a new one. 
Noting that there is no unique delimiter for the information in the cell.

if there is a way to justify the data to look like below:

```
192.168.1.1/24
198.255.4.1/23
192.168.2.5/24
255. 255.10. 0
1 . 1 . 1  . 1
```

in this way I will be able to split them through "text to columns"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without VBA it is a bit tricky. One way which might work is to take the cells which have several lines of text and run them through text-to-column with a newline as the delimiter (entered as Ctrl + J in the text-to-columns dialog). Then transpose the data so that you now have 5 rows of cells rather than a single cell. Now do text-to-column again with a dot as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you, @John Coleman, is there a way to delete all empty cells at once?

Comment: `Goto` (which can be invoked with Ctrl+G) has an option "Special ... Blanks" which can be used to select all blank cells in a region. Perhaps you can use that followed by right-click...delete...shift cells up